# Transform Rotate Menu Item Circular Menu

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have modified a circular menu that I found [on this pen](https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/gbYNYe)
But I am having trouble rotating the menu items around the main circle. By default of this pen, the button's bottom part is perpendicular to it's relative position, but since I changed them with font icons, they look upside down or crooked.

I'm a CSS noob, so I need some help please, been at this for hours!

I've tried a couple of things like:

```css
menu li::after{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

or something like

```css
menu li li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
}
```

None of them seems to be working. Currently my component looks like this:

[image: broken menu image icons upside down]

Here is my full CSS and HTML...

```css
menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background-color: #2e7bbd;
  margin: -45px 0 0 -45px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

menu:before, menu:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 3px;
  height: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fbfdff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

menu:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
menu:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

menu li {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
  width: 59.4px;
  height: 59.4px;
  margin: -29.7px 0 0 -29.7px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 59.4px;
  color: #fbfdff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #428dce;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

menu li::after{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  animation-name: crazy;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
}

menu:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

menu:hover li {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(359deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(310deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(310deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(260deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(260deg) translate(0, 90px);
}
```

```html
<!--<menu>
    <li><i className="fas fa-bell"></i></li>
    <li><i className="fas fa-cog"></i></li>
    <li><i className="fas fa-terminal"></i></li>
</menu>-->

<menu>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</menu>
```

Comment: add `box-sizing:border-box` to avoid the ellipse effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has fixed your rotation problem. please check my code.

I have added after each li and set rotation in after, here is the code what I added.

```
menu li i{
  content: "1";
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

menu li:nth-of-type(1) i {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

menu li:nth-of-type(2) i {
  transform: rotate(230deg);
}

menu li:nth-of-type(3) i {
  transform: rotate(280deg);
}
```

And this is your full code.

```
menu {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background-color: #2e7bbd;
  margin: -45px 0 0 -45px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  z-index: 99999;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

menu:before, menu:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 3px;
  height: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fbfdff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

menu:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
menu:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

menu li {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
  width: 59.4px;
  height: 59.4px;
  margin: -29.7px 0 0 -29.7px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 59.4px;
  color: #fbfdff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #428dce;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  animation-name: crazy;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
}

menu:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

menu:hover li {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(359deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(310deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(310deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(260deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(260deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu li i{
  content: "1";
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

menu li:nth-of-type(1) i {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

menu li:nth-of-type(2) i {
  transform: rotate(230deg);
}

menu li:nth-of-type(3) i {
  transform: rotate(280deg);
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
    <menu>
    <li><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: With this code, I am seeing three items in the correct direction, but with red background and content: "1".... when I remove the background color, the content doesn't stay as 1, it goes back to the icons but they are still upside down. Same goes when I remove the content: "1" from the menu li::after declaration. I'm confused.

Comment: please check this link, I have created  in codepen with your font awesome icon

https://codepen.io/manishankat/pen/arQLmY?editors=1100

Comment: And I have changed my answer please check again

Answer (score 0):

```css
menu {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background-color: #2e7bbd;
  margin: -45px 0 0 -45px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

menu:before, menu:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 3px;
  height: 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fbfdff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

menu:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
menu:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

menu li {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
  width: 59.4px;
  height: 59.4px;
  margin: -29.7px 0 0 -29.7px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 59.4px;
  color: #fbfdff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #428dce;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

menu li::after{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 0);
  animation-name: crazy;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
}

menu li li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
}

menu:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

menu:hover li {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(359deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(310deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(310deg) translate(0, 90px);
}

menu:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(260deg) translate(0, 90px);
  transform: rotate(260deg) translate(0, 90px);
}
li a {
  transform :rotate(180deg);
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
</menu>
```

wrap your list content in a block element or inline element like i did! and rotate this element 180deg!

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your rotation problem.

```
li a {
  transform :rotate(180deg);
}
```

Also if you need a proper circular design for `+` icon, you need to fix `width` and `height` for `.menu` class in CSS as follow:

```
  width: 30px;
  height: 70px;
```

Comment: yeah but with this, every item in the list rotates by 180 degrees